# maven dependency repository with dots in folder's name

Tags: maven

There I described a problem: [maven can't find dependencies [dependencyResolutionException]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296181/maven-cant-find-dependencies-dependencyresolutionexception)

But when I start to analyze the url from which `maven` try to download object I saw

```
http://artifacts.com/rep/com/project/rest/common/2.0.5/common-2.0.5.pom
```

that it uses `com/project/rest` path. But in the repository in `artifacts.com` it has folder with `com.project.rest` and not subfolder structure.

How to resolve it? How to make maven download from

```
http://artifacts.com/rep/com.projet.rest/common/2.0.5/common-2.0.5.pom
```

Comment: Could you possibly instead shout at `artifacts.com` for using wrong folder structure?

Comment: If  `artifacts.com`  has dot's instead of slashes than it is no maven repository and you shouldn't use it. Or you need to change your groupId accordingly.

Comment: Well it's originally gradle repository. Or Ivy. The problem is that I don't know how to change `groupId` in that case

Comment: If `artifacts.com` uses the wrong folder structure and you only have 1 artifact to get from there, just download it manually and install it into your local repo. This workaround is ok because it's not a SNAPSHOT.